# Symbolic link for plist launch daemon

Tags: plist, launchd

I need to store plist in web folder. Is it possible to create a symbolic link for this plist from the `/library/launchDaemon` directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
ln -s /Library/LaunchDaemons/parag.plist
```